# can't download laravel/socialite [laravel5.5]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am in trouble installing laravel/socialite in my VPS to equip twitter login.
Firstly I hit command 'composer require laravel/socialite'.
Then an error below has occurred.

I have to rewrite or make some changes on 'composer.json', right?
I found an articles on Internet that told me do 'composer update'.
Do you have any idea to resolve this error?

laravel5.5
composer version: Composer version 1.8.4 2019-02-11 10:52:10

```
    Using version ^4.4 for laravel/socialite
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - illuminate/http v7.9.2 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.9.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.9.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.8.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.8.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.7.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.7.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.6.2 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.6.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.6.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.5.2 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.5.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.5.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.4.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.3.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.2.2 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.2.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.2.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.16.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.16.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.15.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.14.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.14.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.13.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.12.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.11.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.10.3 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.10.2 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.10.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.10.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.1.3 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.1.2 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.1.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.1.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.0.8 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.0.7 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.0.6 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.0.5 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.0.4 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.0.3 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.0.2 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.0.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v7.0.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.8.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.7.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.6.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.6.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.6.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.5.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.5.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.5.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.4.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.3.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.2.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.9 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.8 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.7 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.6 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.5 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.4 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.3 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.20 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.19 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.18 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.17 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.16 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.15 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.14 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.13 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.12 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.11 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.10 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.18.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.17.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.17.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.16.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.15.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.15.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.14.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.13.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.13.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.12.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.11.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.10.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.1.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.0.4 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.0.3 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.0.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.0.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/http v6.0.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - laravel/socialite v4.4.0 requires illuminate/http ~5.7.0|~5.8.0|^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - laravel/socialite v4.4.1 requires illuminate/http ~5.7.0|~5.8.0|^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - don't install illuminate/http v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.49
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.5.49, required as 5.5.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.49].
    - Installation request for laravel/socialite ^4.4 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[v4.4.0, v4.4.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: Update your composer by `composer self-update` and try again.

Comment: @pery check my answer. It will solve your problem

Comment: [ErrorException]
  rename(/usr/local/bin/composer): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

The current socialite release is not work for Laravel 5.5. So you will update your laravel to latest version and use socialite will work.

Ref: [Socialize v4.1 not install on laravel 5.5](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/issues/366)